# Hibernate + Spring two persistence units with their own entity subsets

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring but in general I am aware of it's features so I decided to use it in one of my projects. Main problem however is with Hibernate. Before this idea of introducing spring the premise is this:

My application (not web) had to connect to a DB and gather information from it using "persistence_1.xml" with it's own set of entity classes. In other words everything related to "persistence_1.xml" was read only so that no tragedies would occur. Also "persistence_1.xml" with persistence-unit of name "p1" came from web-app dependencies. So picture is this: my app (not-web) written with the support of maven, took dependencies of the other application to access database and gather information.

And the other "persistence_2.xml" with persistence-unit name of "p2" and it's own subset of entities was created by me to store gathered and processed information into the same database.

So originally I had two entity managers one responsible for "p1" another for "p2".

I have seen some material on the internet where they show how to configure two entity managers with different dataSources but I can not figure out how to create two entity managers in SPRING using their own set of ENTITIES.

Let's say "test" is only associated with "UserEntity" and "dummy" is only associted with "DumbEntity".

Now everything get's mashed up along the way and no matter which PU name I type in in @PersistenceContext(name = "test") - it can query for any entity in database. 
This is example of `persistence.xml:`

```
<persistence-unit name="test" type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.test.db.UserEntity</class>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="dummy" type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.test.db.DumbEntity</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Bean definition:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="dummy" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean name="userDao" class="org.test.services.UserDaoImpl" />
```

My UserDaro service

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
private EntityManager entityManager;


public UserDaoImpl() {

}

public UserDaoImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Override
public void saveUser(UserEntity user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Override
public void saveUser(DumbEntity user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
}

@Override
public List<UserEntity> fetchAllUsers() {
    String sql = "FROM UserEntity";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
    return query.getResultList();
}

@Override
public List<DumbEntity> fetchAllUsers2() {
    String sql = "FROM DumbEntity";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

}

In any way whether or not I use fetchAllUsers() or fetchAllUsers2() I get the result, but I would like that each of these would only work with entityManager that only has the knowledge about about specific entities.

I would like you to share your thoughts on this one. Thank You.

Comment: Well, I have figured out one way of doing such thing is adding "<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>" in each persistence-unit declaration.